# My switch statement is going straight to the default statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

```
   var comics = prompt("hey do you like comic books? y or n").toUpperCase();
    switch(comics){
       case "do you like comics":
           if(comics === "y" || comics === "yes" || comics === "Yes") {
            prompt("Sweet!");
       }else{
          console.log("ummmm wrong answer");

      break;
    }


   var comics = prompt("so do you like batman or superman??").toUpperCase();
       case "sylk":
        //So You Like Comics
            if(answr === "superman" || answr === "Superman" && answr === "batman" || answr === "Batman");
            console.log("dude thats awesome me too!!");
            break;
         default:
             window.alert("uh can you re-type that??");
```

}

It goes from the prompt straight to the default:, 
    I don't get it I even have `break;`'s and stuff.

Comment: You do not declare `answr` . Also, your codes are incomplete. Please at least post the whole switch case.

Comment: I though it doesn't matter about the declaration for `answr` . @ShivanRaptor

Answer (score 5):

Your syntax is wrong

There is no [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) in your code, you need to pass the user option `comics` to switch then write the cases inside the `switch block`

```
var comics = prompt("so do you like batman or superman??").toLowerCase();
switch(comics){
    case "sylk": 
        //So You Like Comics
        if(answr === "yes" || answr === "Yes" || answr === "y")
            console.log("dude thats awesome me too!!");
        break;
    default:
        window.alert("uh can you re-type that??");

}
```

Comment: thanks new programmer still trying to learn good writing techniques. @Arun P Johny